# DOM based XSS inside src attribute

Tags: xss, javascript, dom

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
var url= document.location.href;
document.write("<img src='?bla="+document.location.href+"'>");
```

I am able to inject code when I append e.g. `?b=a'onX=alert(1);'` to the URL, but this only works in browsers where `'` will not get encoded.

Are there any other attacks that I didn't consider? Is there another way to break out of the `src` attribute?

Answer (score 2):

> Are there any other attacks that I didn't consider?

To prevent the single quote form getting encoded, you could try to sneak your payload into the path instead of the query string. For example, if the vulnerable page resides at `http://example.com/path/vulnerable.php` you could try something like this:

```
http://example.com/'onerror='payload/..%2Fpath/vulnerable.php
```

The idea is that some servers resolve the path implicitly. They don't check if the first folder `'onerror='payload` actually exists, but immediately switch back to the parent directory (`../`) and resolve the rest of the path without issuing any redirect. (URL-encoding the slash as `%2f` prevents your browser from automatically shortening the path.)

> Is there another way to break out of the src attribute?

No, a matching quote is your only chance to escape from the attribute value as explained in [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/142334/95381).

Comment: The Server runs Apache and unfortunately it doesn't work, thanks anyway! :)