# XSS payload without - &<>"=()

Tags: xss

Is it possible to construct a XSS payload without the use of these chars - &<>"=()? The server is not doing any output encoding.

Consider both the cases where the user input is being put into 1. attribute value, 2. HTML body.

Comment: OWASP XSS Evasion Cheat Sheet is your friend - https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: if you cloud insert `()` you cloud use the http://www.jsfuck.com/ to write the XSS you want and it will be converted to only this symbols: `()+[]!`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Arminius covered it pretty well. But there are exceptions depending on the HTML attribute. Here are just two examples (others exist, mostly related to URLs, but `onX` and some other attributes are also special cases; additionally, with the use of JS frameworks [script gadgets](https://2017.appsec.eu/presos/Hacker/Don%E2%80%99t%20trust%20the%20DOM%20Bypassing%20XSS%20mitigations%20via%20Script%20gadgets%20-%20Sebastian%20Lekies,%20Krzystof%20Kotowicz%20and%20Eduardo%20Vela%20Nava%20-%20OWASP_AppSec-Eu_2017.pdf) may also be used).

href attribute:

```
// user-supplied link:
<a href="[user_input]">click</a>
```

attack:

```
javascript:alert`1`
```

meta attribute:

```
// user-supplied link for redirect:
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=[user_input]">
```

attack:

```
data:text/html;base64,PHNjcmlwdD5hbGVydCgndGVzdDMnKTwvc2NyaXB0Pg
```

Answer (score 5):

**Generally, no.** At least not without preconditions (some of which [@tim has lined out](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/173048/95381)), because:

- You can only escape [from an attribute value by introducing the matching quote](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/142333/xss-inside-html-attribute-where-and-are-filtered/142334#142334). (I assume you're referring to a double-quoted attribute, so a payload without `"` doesn't get you beyond the attribute value. Obviously, you could escape from a single-quoted attribute because `'` isn't blacklisted, or from an unquoted one by using a space.)
- In the data state (outside of any tags) you can only achieve XSS by introducing new tags. Everything else is just treated as data. So if `<` is blacklisted, you're out of luck.