# Is possible ot create XSS with theses chars?

Tags: xss

As part of bug bounty, I have a PATCH request to the API to change my name.
I can post theses chars:

```
:
;
'
*
`
=
#
/
[
]
(
)
```

This is the HTML result :

```
data-cy="label-input__input" value="My injection :;'*`=#/[]()" class="label-input__input" data-v-71bcf264> <!---->
```

Am I obligated to use the char `"` to inject my JavaScript ?
I already visited the page : [XSS payload without - &<>"=()](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/173032/xss-payload-without) but the following code doesn't works:

```
javascript:alert`1`
```

Comment: To security is only the idea related. The implementation questions as in your case are pure programming technique. That's why this question can be better answered on SO.

Comment: You'll have to escape from the `value` attribute to perform an xss. Since the value attribute starts with a `"`, it must also be closed with a `"`. So no, you cannot perform an xss here if you can't use a `"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not in the context you have here.

URIs like `javascript` will not work in a `value` attribute, so you'll need to escape that context. You can only do that with `"`, which you don't have.

With the limited characters you do have, you'd either need an injection where you can use `javascript` URIs (eg into `href`), an injection into an attribute value context enclosed by `'` (or not enclosed at all), an injection into a JavaScript context (eg a javascript variable enclosed by `'`), a bypass of the filter (maybe via some encoding, though unlikely), or insecure handling of the value via JavaScript (eg the input being passed to `eval`).